# Toolbar overlaps LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

I have a LinearLayout with 2 inner LinearLayouts. If I add the Toolbar in this layout-file it always overlaps the whole layout. So only the Toolbar is visible. In the other layout-files it worked without any problem.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          tools:context="de.dk.mafi.ActMain">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:padding="2dp"
    app:titleMarginStart="20dp"
    app:titleTextAppearance="@style/MyMaterialTheme.Base.TitleTextStyle"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Favoriten"/>


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/training"/>

    <Button android:id="@+id/button" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Hauptmenü"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: you can try adding  android:fitsSystemWindows=“true”. refer to https://medium.com/google-developers/why-would-i-want-to-fitssystemwindows-4e26d9ce1eec#.q6n66hugs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `LinearLayout` has a wrong orientation. It should be set with `vertical`, instead of `horizontal` which gives the other children (as the inner `LinearLayout`s) to be draw after the `Toolbar` on the right outside the width screen. Change to:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      ...
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

Then, remove the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` from the `Toolbar`.

**EDIT:**

I just did this, it works as expected:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="...">

    <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/blue"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/red"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where I'm reusing this Toolbar layout on other Activities:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Output:

[image: Screenshot of Toolbar above two LinearLayouts]

My test contains above/below inner children, but to keep your requirements, juste add a parent container for the children, easily do as:

```
<LinearLayout ...>

   <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

   <!-- use a parent container with horizontal orientation -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:orientation="horizontal">

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" .../>

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1" .../>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've already tried it, but it shows the same result (in the preview of Android Studio).

Comment: @DenoAgüero It seems to work as expected (see my edit). Maybe you have to check with the inner children of the 2 linearlayouts. You should avoid nested weight for better performance.

Comment: Thank you. But now my layouts are among each other and not side by side.

Comment: @DenoAgüero so you want the toolbar on top and then the two inner LinearLayouts side by side? It would probably be easier then, to replace the outer LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout.

Comment: @DenoAgüero oh sorry, I didn't notice that you want side by side. Edited ;)